# what the advantage of h264 Annex-B VS AVCC

Tags: video-streaming, h.264

Annex-B cost a lot time to split NALU in the video stream which we should look for every StartCode。

I wonder in which case we should use Annex-B

Answer (score 1):

> *"Annex-B cost a lot time to split NALU"*

There are things you can do:

- Skip in 4-byte jumps where you check if the landed byte has a "zero"...
   then check if it's part of a start code integer (4 bytes).
- Use a [Reserved NALU](https://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/) type (ignored by decoders) to pre-store a frame's bytes length.
- (Idea from [FLV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video#Flash_Video_Structure)):
   Instead of Reserved NALU, just append the frame length at frame byte's ending.
  (frame can still be decoded, even with some extra bytes at NALU's ending).
- Contain it in a streamable format like AVI, FLV, MPEG-TS, Fragmented MP4 (MPEG-ISOBMFF).

> *"I wonder in which case we should use Annex-B"*

These two formats are there for solving situations where the H.264 video is either:

- **AVCC** is best option for: a **stored file** (with known sizes & offsets).
- **AnnexB** is best option for: a **live-stream** (with unknown lengths of bytes).

Imagine an *image* encoder that generates one frame's image on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

(1) Every time it has a color (one RGB pixel) it transmits that pixel (as a "unit"). 
(2) The decoder re-builds the image on a pixel-by-pixel process, by received units. 
(3) The decoder will know when to stop when it gets a new frame image's **start-code**.

An H.264 encoder/decoder process is similar.
 The smallest H.264 "unit" you can transmit is one macroblock (usually 16x16 pixels, but which itself can be further sliced into smaller quarters such as 4x4 pixel blocks).

The decoder re-builds the frame/image, not pixel-by-pixel, but instead on a macroblock-by-macroblock level. One macroblock's pixels are decoded, and then is followed by next received macroblock. If there are missing macroblocks then the frame image will have "blocks" of mid-grey areas (where R/G/B == 128).